# Xamarin - ResourceNotFoundException when inflating layout

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I'm writing an Android application using Xamarin, that works with our storage management application.
I'm using ZXing(.Net).Mobile for barcode scanning.
No matter what method I use of invoking the barcode scanner (this all started this morning; everything worked up until then...), I always get the following error:

`Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException`

`File res/drawable/randomfile.png from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020001`

The error is always pointed at resource files which I have added to the application, but have nothing to do with the call at hand.

This error, for instance, is thrown with this line of code:

```
// ZXingScannerFragment.cs:20

frame = (FrameLayout)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.zxingscannerfragmentlayout, viewGroup, false);
```

The stack trace isn't pointing to any of my code, only code provided by the library and the underlying framework(s).

Here is the code that basically "initiates" the fragment (I've tried this with the MobileBarcodeScanner class with these *exact* results!)

```
private void DisplayScanner(ZXingScannerFragment scanner) => SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                              .Replace(Resource.Id.linearLayout1, scanner, "ZxingFragment")
                              .Commit();
```

Also, the exception mentions something about a corrupt XML file, but the XML files shown in the IDE are all without (detectable) errors?

---

Code stacktrace:

```
--- End of managed Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException stack trace ---
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/networkteam_neu.png from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020001
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:988)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
    at md5403c779e0873343748dae1dd78d537ec.ZXingScannerFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at md5403c779e0873343748dae1dd78d537ec.ZXingScannerFragment.onCreateView(ZXingScannerFragment.java:31)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:525)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:973)
    ... 18 more
```

Of course, the Source and TargetSize fields are null.

---

Any and all help with the matter would be much appreciated; the deadline is in a few hours and now I'm back to square one.

Comment: Not sure I get the question?

Comment: When you add the `randomfile.png` to your project, what is its `Build Action` ?

Comment: It's an Android Resource (or whatever the default is).
I can use it from the main activity, but it's completely unrelated to the barcode scanner.